# Question regarding prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

Is the following statement true?:
"If $n$ is an integer ($n \geq 2$) then 
$\frac {1}{n^2} \left(\binom{2n}{n}-2\right)$ is an integer if and only if $n$ is prime."

Comment: Did you just observed it or found it somewhere??

Comment: I found it as a conjecture in another forum. It seems to be true but I can't prove it. I don't know if this is a well known result or not.

Comment: Can you give a reference of this conjecture?

Comment: Some quick thoughts. You can re-write $a_n=\binom{2n}{n}-2$ as: $$2\frac{(2n-1\dots(n+1))}{(n-1)!}-2$$ which is an (even) integral, since the product of (more than) $k$ consecutive numbers is divided by $k!$. Also, $$n^2=\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)$$. So, it boils down to show that the solutions of $$2\frac{(2n-1)\dots(n+1)}{(n-1)!}-2\equiv0\mod n^2$$ are only prime numbers. Another thought is that, being able to show this equivalnce, wouldn't mean that we would have found a way to generate prime numbers - if $n$ is prime then $a_n/n^2\in\mathbb{Z}$ and vice versa - which is unsolvable, up to now?

Comment: See Babbage's theorem in [this](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0012365X98003641/1-s2.0-S0012365X98003641-main.pdf?_tid=31a8643e-6e18-11e7-b4af-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1500643765_2c8e08245bfc791c74d48065f5a57cfc) paper .

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Comment: With Babbage's result in the article together with the identity C(n, k)=(n/k)C(n-1, k-1) it now seems easy to prove the conjecture in one direction.